# What is the parameter to evaluate the mixing level in reactor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm designing a continuous flow reactor which can remove the pollutant through chemical reaction. With more mixing in the reactor, the pollutant from the inflow can interact with the reactant more intensively, thereby improve the removal efficiency.

I have built an fluid dynamic model with certain geometry shape. And I want to evaluate the mixing level inside of the reactor by changing the shape using Computational Fluid Dynamics(CFD) tool. Then, I can choose a best layout for fabricating in reality.

More specifically, suppose there are two reactors in the same shape, inserting some baffles inside one reactor will improve its mass transport ability as my expectation.

What parameters  can I choose as the evaluation index?

- turbulence kinetic energy
- diffusion coefficient

  > IMHO, the mass transfer is composed by convention and diffusion. The convention process is dominated by the inflow velocity(bulk phase movement), and the diffusion coefficient will also influence the mixing level

Any other better parameters can be deemed as the index to evaluate the mixing level inside certain fluid field?

Comment: Can't your CFD model also do mixing transport?  Maybe you could fake it out by using temperature as a tracer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your simulation already simulate the evolution of a pollutant/tracer component? In that case the parameter you should be interested in is the so-called Homogeneity parameter:
$$H=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N c_i^2 - \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\right)^2}}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N c_i}$$
which is defined as the standard deviation over the mean of the spatial distribution of the concentration.

Of course how well something is mixed is subjective; you could follow $H$ as a function of time until $H<0.01$ which would give you $t_{99\%}$, i.e. the time until $99\%$ of the pollutant/tracer has mixed.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I have not done the part of chemical transport model by inserting tracers. For now, I want to design the reactor's shape by evaluate its hydraulic field.

Comment: @HanZhengzu I think in that case you would be interested in residence time distribution modeling in mixing tanks.